# JAVA - Parsing into 2 strings total

Tags: java, parsing

I have a string which I want to split using a certain set of delimiters, but I would like to split it into 2 strings exactly. This means that if the string is "ax,yt,zr" I want to split it into "ax" and "yt,zr". What is the cleanest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use substring.

```
String text = "ax,yt,zr";
String strOne = text.substring(0, text.indexOf(','));
String strTwo = text.substring(text.indexOf(','));
```

Comment: How about if I would like it to use multiple delimiters at the same time? (for example,split on comma or space, whichever it finds first

Comment: @Trup, the regex answer handles that easily: `"ab cd,ef".split(" ,",2)`

Answer (score 7):

[String.split(String regex, int limit)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

for eaxmple:

```
"ax,yt,zr".split(",", 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            String g = "ax,yt,zr";
            String r = g.substring(0,g.indexOf(","));
            String f = g.substring(g.indexOf(","),g.length());
            System.out.println(r + " " + f);
```

indexOf:  returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified substring.